# Why some airliners have autostart and others don't?

Tags: boeing-737, engine, boeing-747, boeing-787, fadec

So some of the more modern FADEC equiped planes (specifically airliners like the 787) have autostart and will self monitor the engines during startup. The one thing that confused me was how a 747 could have auto start, and another 747 wouldn't have it. Is the auto start built into FADEC or is there a separate component necessary? Also, why doesn't the 737 NG have Auto start?

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that not all models of the 747 are equipped with FADEC. The aircraft was first introduced in 1968. FADEC-1 was introduced in 1988. It would make sense that all 747's made during those 20 years would not have it.